# Geotiff to NetCDF with gdal_translate: Huge increase in filesize

Tags: compression, gis, gdal, netcdf, netcdf4

I have downloaded files in Geotiff format with which I want to do some statistical
analysis. Therefore I have converted the Geotiffs with gdal_translate into NetCDF files.
The problem is that it leads to an enormous file size growth, from ~20 MB to ~1.6 GB.

Did anyone have the same problem and has any advice?
The data can be found here: ftp://anon-ftp.ceda.ac.uk/neodc/esacci/fire/data/burned_area/MODIS/pixel/v5.1/compressed/

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is always the case going from geotiff to standard netcdf with gdal_translate. Have you tried compressing the files in netcdf4 format with e.g.

```
cdo -f nc4 -z zip9 copy in.nc out.nc
```

?